# Assign the literal string as a property of a dynamic object during runtime and access it

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, expandoobject

How can I assign the fieldname of a sqldatareader during runtime dynamically to a dynamic object?

Lets assume I have read the fieldname of a SqlDataReader into a variable:

```
string sqlDataReaderFieldNameStringVariable  = reader.GetName(index);
```

I can not say:

```
dynamic dyn = new ExpandoObject();
dyn.sqlDataReaderFieldNameStringVariable = "test";
```

How can I do that?

UPDATE:

still time to get a point ;-) I add my dyn object to a List of type ExpandoObject which is the return value of a method. When I access the list via data[0].test property does not exist while compile time ???

When I do this outside of the method returning the List:

```
dynamic bla = (ExpandoObject)data[0];
            String shit = bla.Name;
```

Why do I have to cast it? Any workaround? Thanks Jon.

Comment: just return a `List<dynamic>` instead

Comment: this is great! another point goes to you because you were 11 mins ago :P

Comment: It's called "votes" - but since you only upvoted 2 answers in all of your 27 questions I won't hold my breath ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cast your `ExpandoObject` `dyn` to `IDictionary<string, object>` first to do that:

```
dynamic dyn = new ExpandoObject();
var dynDict = dyn as IDictionary<string, object>;
dynDict[sqlDataReaderFieldNameStringVariable] = "test";
```

Comment: string val = dyn.test; shit it works. Dynamics are cool :P @BrokenGlass When I refreshed my Browser you were first before Jon ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For *most* dynamic objects, it's tricky. Doable (using `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`) but tricky. If you're *really* using [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx), it's simple because that implements `IDictionary<string, object>`:

```
dynamic dyn = new ExpandoObject();
var dictionaryView = (IDictionary<string, object>) dyn;
dictionaryView[sqlDataReaderFieldNameStringVariable] = "test";
```

Comment: still time to get a point ;-) I add my dyn object to a List of type ExpandoObject which is the return value of a method. When I access the list via data[0].test property does not exist while compile time ???

Comment: @Pascal: I'm finding it hard to parse your comment - but if you could write it as an edit to your question, I'll see what I can do...

Comment: @Pascal: You have to cast it in order for the expression to be of type `dynamic` - unless that's the static type of the expression, the compiler will try to use "normal" static binding.

Comment: I upvoted you now Jon because you do not deserve that above all not when its uncommented from a troll ;-)